# Java Internationalization (i18n) Libraries/Frameworks

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, internationalization

My organisation is about to embark on the long process of internationalizing (i16g?) its corporate website. The website is a mix of Java EE (JSP/Servlets, no EJB) and static content pushed from the (Documentum) WCM.

While I have experience using the "built-in" mechanism of using `ResourceBundle`'s along with the associated properties files for each language/locale (containing the "KEY=Translated value" approach), where we simply reference the KEY value where we want the translated text to appear.

My director has mentioned that he has used a different approach at a previous organisation whereby they used a 3rd-party library (he does not recall the actual name) which included the actual [english] text in the webpage (to aid developers) which was replaced at run time with the translated content from the config xml file. *(anyone know which library this would be?)*

I am interested in what other approaches/libraries/frameworks there might be out there to facilitate this.

Thanks

Comment: I'll give the question another day or so before I make a decision.

Comment: Just for clarification that XML file wasn't a TMX file right? TMX file being way more sophisticated resource bundle equivalent (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_Memory_eXchange).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your boss probably meant [gettext](http://code.google.com/p/gettext-commons/), just like @Pawel Dyda mentioned, but [cosmopolitan](https://github.com/rodionmoiseev/c10n/wiki/Overview) may also be of interest to you.

Comment: Yes, it seems that "gettext" was what was used in the previous organisation - am still looking into it to see if we want to go down that route.

Comment: I have selected this answer as the correct one, mainly as it gives exactly what I requested, and doesn't launch into a diatribe on a matter that was not requested.

Answer (score 5):

My company also maintains a GNU gettext-related library for Java (and very soon with extensions aimed at Scala).

Not only does it support all of the goodness of GNU gettext, it also simplifies output AND input of date/timestamps and currency, include facilities for using "wiki" formatting in translations (so you can output HTML bold on a word, for example), java message formatting, generalized "escape" support (so the output can be auto-escaped for inclusion, say, in HTML), and currency rounding.

It is open-source, and currently on github at https://github.com/awkay/easy-i18n/

Answer (score 4):

When I hear you are using `ResourceBundle`s, I see something like this:

```
ResourceBundle rb = ResourceBundle.getBundle("messages", locale);
String someString = rb.getString("some.key");
```

If this is your approach for Java Server Pages (using such snippets in scriplets), this is ***wrong***. Instead, you should use JSTL or Spring message tags.

As for your inquiry, I believe they used Gettext (sorry no link, as I am running out of time).
This is not necessary the best approach. JSTL approach is the most common for JSP and you should stick to it, unless you have very good reasons not to.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more explicit - yes, I did mean i'd be using `ResourceBumndle`'s in conjunction with JSTL tags (we don't do scriptlets) :) - Thanks for your input, I'll investigate gettext and see if that rings any bells.

Answer (score 1):

It worth looking at http://alexsexton.com/blog/2012/03/the-ux-of-language/ it has a good explanation of the idea behind gettext and the limitations of the gettext design a better approach to gettext is the ICU message format this is what the JDK MessageFormat class is based, on http://site.icu-project.org/home there is also a javascript library based on the ICU message format https://github.com/SlexAxton/messageformat.js

Answer (score 1):

I hope, it's not too late to suggest one more solution: https://github.com/resource4j/resource4j

This library has integration with Thymeleaf web page renderer, which solves the problem you've mentioned: you include in page template the English text and then substitute it with localized version in runtime.